# How to convert text to vector for CSV files using Python and find euclidean distance

Tags: python

I want to convert text into vector for CSV files using Python.

`def text_to_vector` in my code is throwing an error.

```
import re,math
from collections import Counter

WORD = re.compile(r'\w+')

   def euclidean_distance(vec1,vec2):
      intersection = set(vec1.keys()) & set(vec2.keys())
      return sqrt(sum(pow(vec1[x]-vec2[x],2) for x in intersection)

   def text_to_vector(text):
      words = WORD.findall(text)
      return Counter(words)

 #text1 = 'This is a foo bar sentence .'
 #text2 = 'This sentence is similar to a foo bar sentence .'
 text1 = file('Stacks1.csv').read()
 text2= file('reftopics.csv').read()
 vector1 = text_to_vector(text1)
 vector2 = text_to_vector(text2)

 euclidean = euclidean_distance(vector1, vector2)*100

 print 'Euclidean:', euclidean
```

Comment: What's the error/errormessage? Beside your missusing of listcomprehensions in `euclidean_distance()` and the wrong indentation there is no obvious error to me.

Answer (score 0):

`euclidean_distance(vec1, vec2)` should be something like:

```
def euclidean_distance(vec1, vec2):
    intersection = set(vec1.keys()) & set(vec2.keys())
    return math.sqrt(sum([pow(vec1[s]-vec2[s], 2) for s in intersection]))
```

Your use of list comprehensions is wrong.